# Styles are not shown for the selected item in Eclipse's CompletionProposal popup

Tags: eclipse-plugin

I am working on an Eclipse plugin and now implementing some code completion proposals for class members where I show the members' visibility using a colored square.
I have implemented `ICompletionProposalExtension6` for this so the lines can have styles. The squares are practically colored Unicode square characters.

It almost works as I want except that colors are not shown for the selected item, its text is converted to the color configured by `setProposalSelectorForeground()` (see the black square in the image).

Is it possible to change the selector so the colors are preserved?

[image]

Comment: If I read the source correctly this is done in `org.eclipse.jface.internal.text.TableOwnerDrawSupport` which explicitly ignores the colours for the selected line.  This is used by `org.eclipse.jface.text.contentassist.CompletionProposalPopup`. Probably very difficult to override.

Comment: Thanks for checking this. I will try to live with this limitation (and maybe I will file a bug to get this improved).